# How to get an axis in camera coordinate system pybullet?

Tags: robotic-arm, computer-vision, stereo-vision, transformation

I am using pybullet to render a robot simulation. This robot have 2 joints and hence, 2 corresponding axes of rotation. I know that when I use `getJointInfo` on this joint, the joint axis returned will be in local coordinate frame.

I want to know that how can I convert these local coordinates into camera coordinates.

For now I know that if I get the joint axis in world space, I can get the axis in camera coordinate by doing a dot product of the axis in world space and view matrix.

Please explain the process in detail as I am a beginner with transformation stuff.